# How to change UILabel size if label is truncated in Xcode (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am developing a would you rather app and what happens is that some of my questions are too big to fit my label... Is there a way that if there is too much text for the label to fit it will change the size of the label (specifically the height in my case). I've found a couple of answers but:

1. I am new to Xcode so they are all a bit complex
2. They are written in Objective-C instead of Swift

Comment: can you show some code, how you are setting up your UILabel.

Comment: Use Autolayout. Set constraints for the position and the width and the label will adjust its height automatically

Comment: You need to set the maximum lines (`Lines` in interface builder / `numberOfLines` in code) to how many lines you need (or `0` for unlimited lines) and line break to `Word Wrap` to avoid truncation.

Comment: You can use autolayout to resize the label according to your text. if your are working with code then please share your code

Answer (score 1):

Add constraints to your label & set **number of lines to 0** & **line break to Word wrap**.

[image: Normal Label]

**Table View Cell:**
In the case of `tableviewcell` add below lines in your `viewdidload` and apply the settings mentioned in the storyboard screenshot.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

[image: table view Cell]

Comment: The first part even works with a `UILabel` inside a `UITableViewCell`, no need to set the actual height (Xcode 12.4/Swift 5).

Answer (score 0):

Simply call **sizeToFit** on UILabel.

```
myLabel.sizeToFit()
```